# Create mobile application for a website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mobile, wrapper

I'm already creating a asp.net jQuery mobile web application and it's mobile responsive.
Now i want create a simple mobile app that can be installed in mobile devises, simple as a wrapper that show directly the website when the app open.

My question is: what's the easy and free way to do it? Will Google and Apple accept my app? 
knowing that i want make it for android and ios devises 
thanks to you all

Comment: My advice - don't make an app if you're just going to show you site. You might think you're going to get more exposure, but you'll just be spamming. A better way to do it will be to make your site responsive (using CSS3 media queries), and create a mobile app as an added accessory to your experience

Answer (score 0):

If your site already work on mobile devices and you simply want to add it to the app store's of apple and google you should check out PhoneGap.

http://phonegap.com/

This way you simply warp you site into a file that can be installed.
Becuse your site is .net it cant be run from the mobile device (server-side) you need to chose :
one way is to make that index.html of the app to redirect to your site or you can built with html+css+js a small site that use web services to your server.